# How to Fit my continuous data with hmmlearn GMMHMM library in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hidden-markov-models, markov, hmmlearn

I am trying to implement HMM Learning/training with the continuous data set which is in sequential form. I have tried to construct a new HMM training with Gaussian Mixture/EM Algo, but I have been facing some issues, so i switch to `hmmlearn` library in python.

**Overview about my data set**

**For e.g**, A list contains normalized training data.

Total elements inside the list = 75

Each element inside the list is an np array.

The data inside the list is Vehicle driving data which is continuous.

```
'X_train = [[100*4], [100*4], [100*4], [100*4].........................[100*4]]' 
len(X_train) = 75
X_Train[0] = [100*4]
X_Train.columns=['Speed','Angle', 'Acceleration1', 'Acceleration2']
```

Every [100*4] data received from vehicle at specific time intervals. Lets say X_train[0] is 15 to 30 seconds driving study data. X_train[1.] may be 15 to 30 seconds driving study data and so on .....

**problem in hmmlearn**

In **`hmmlearn`** library i would like to clarify some queries. 
My objective is to get the parameters of the trained model for my dataset like initial prob, state transition prob, Gaussian weights, mean & covariance, so,.

Model created with 2 Hidden states with 2 Gaussian

```
model = hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=2, n_mix=2, covariance_type="diag", n_iter=100)
```

**Question 1:**

should I `concatenate` my overall data set into a single list as stated in the document [Working with multiple seq from hmmlearn document](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#multiple-sequences)?

If it is, then my `training data set (X)` will look like with size of `7500 *4`, also, the lengths parameter will have a list like `lengths = [100, 100, 100, ......100]`

Is this the way fit should be implemented?

**Question: 2**

How can i check my EM Algo converges? I have seen the document for **monitor_** 
function. But I am not able to understand.

**Question: 3**

After training, i would like to check the probability (using Forward Algorithm) of non-trained sequence of size 100*4. So what is the required function to apply forward algorithm using trained model parameters?

I have posted many question related to HMM training, But I have no satisfied answers based on my requirement. I hope hmmlearn library helps

Comment: I have the same question. I did it exactly the same way and fitted the model, but it seems not to update its parameter